# Spark SQL dataframe manipulation

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to scala and spark and I am struggling to solve a rather simple problem. Consider the following csv file:

```
val df = spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).csv("/home/USER/test_file.csv")
df.show(false)

df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, measurement: int ... 1 more field]
+---+-----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|id |measurement|location                                            |
+---+-----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|1  |235        |{type: 'point', lon_lat: [-122.03476,37.362517]}    |
|2  |45         |{type: 'point', lon_lat: [115.8614000, -31.9522400]}|
+---+-----------+----------------------------------------------------+

df.printSchema

 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- measurement: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- location: string (nullable = true)
```

I would like to create a dataset with the following schema (data type is not so important as I want to save it to csv later):

```
dataset: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Features] = [id: string, measurement: string, typeattr: string, lon: string, lat: string]

 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- measurement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- typeattr: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lon: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lat: string (nullable = true)
```

My code so far looks like this:

```
case class Features(id: String, measurement:String)

var dataset = df.map(s => {    
            Features(s(0).toString, s(1).toString)
})
```

How can I parse the json string (splitting the "lon_lat" key) into the dataset?

Comment: Is your file csv? I did not see the raw file given. I am assuming that you have csv to start with and one of the column is having json formatted value?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Even though I realized that the format is not vaild json because the double quotes are missing. So I guess the first step would be to convert the string to a vaild json format...

Comment: Then may be the best option is parse the json string manually or using jackson - inside a map for the rdd. This map will take 3 strings and return 5 as your requirement